# How can I ensure that a custom environment variable is set before cron runs a task?

Tags: cron, environment-variables

I recently experienced a [logwatch issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/420313/cannot-run-logwatch-due-to-datemanip-issue) that is fixed by running `export DATE_MANIP=DM5`.
cron seems to forget this when I logout (presumably because it's not saved).

Where can I add this custom environment variable? Since I don't manage the code for logwatch, I don't want to necessarily add an `export` command inside the script that launches.  I tried adding `export DATE_MANIP=DM5` to `/root/.bash_profile` but that doesn't help when I'm not logged in.

CentOS 6.x

Answer (score 3):

Edit your `/etc/cron.daily/0logwatch` script, and add the `export DATE_MANIP=DM5` before the logwatch call.

example:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Set logwatch location
LOGWATCH_SCRIPT="/usr/sbin/logwatch"
#Add options to this line. Most options should be defined in /etc/logwatch/conf/logwatch.conf,
#but some are only for the nightly cronrun such as --output mail and should be set here.
#Other options to consider might be "--format html" or "--encode base64", man logwatch for more details.
OPTIONS="--output mail"

# Fix Date::Manip issue
export DATE_MANIP=DM5

#Call logwatch
$LOGWATCH_SCRIPT $OPTIONS

exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

look into BASH_ENV
http://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/

try checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063618/bash-env-or-sourcing-a-file-in-a-non-interactive-non-login-shell

Comment: That's not going to help: to set the `DATE_MANIP` environment variable, you'd need to set the `BASH_ENV` environment variable, which is the same problem. And even if you did set `BASH_ENV`, it would have no effect on an `sh` script.